# Android:Update signed .APK

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-install-apk

I have created an Android app and used Android google Maps API v2. and generated signed .Apk file, I have a question for you that when I made changes in my project it does not update my signed .Apk file. For example when I change API key in my AndroidManifest.xml Android Studio does not update it in signed APK file. How it is possible to make changes in signed apk file. ? I am new in Android and StackOverFlow, and excuse for all mistakes in asking question, thankx

Comment: once you export your app as signed .apk you need to generate your key again.

Comment: Add that key in the in your Google Console and xml

Comment: 7A:5C:20:09:F1:27:68:29:1A:7D:53:E5:AB:91:74:87:5A:AC:38:59;com.***h.atl****** i put this in google console and got a key from console 
"AIzaSyD9VcQRz3EANuwm_64BcxzRPgWqoxVQjws" now i put this key in my AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Infect this key is for signed apk and does not work for debug apk , So i want to update my signed apk with this key which I got from google for Signed apk

Comment: Just export it as signed .apk with same keystore and use that one,it will work

Comment: sir app is working but Google map is not showing its tiles

Comment: yes, in sign apk,

 Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
    Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
    API Key: AIzaSyAAo-W9TFF6T0YgTP6GaWFdD7WfGagrQXE
    Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): 7A:5C:20:09:F1:27:68:29:1A:7D:53:E5:AB:91:74:87:5A:AC:33:59;com.********.atlas****
    --------- beginning of /dev/log/system

Comment: Did you export signed.apk again after getting the google console key"AIzaSyD9VcQRz3EANuwm_64BcxzRPgWqoxVQjws"?

Comment: Sir the key you mention is for debug version , when I Signed my App, Maps stop working in Signed application but is working in debug app

Answer (score 2):

When you added API key that generated from your `.keystore` then you must built signed `.apk` with the same `keystore` for publishing the app in store.

and when you provide any updates then there is no need to change the API key again but you must built signed `.apk` with the same `keystore` again.

Comment: Sir, I created .APK from menu "Build >  generate Signed APK" and follow  the next steps.When I build APK file at that time Google api key in AndroidManifest.xml was for debug version and Google Map was visible and after conversion to signed apk, google map disappears

Comment: @RajaRapChic That's what i my answer. first you should create your own keysore and generate a new SHA-1 with that keystore then generate a new key with that SHA-1.